# How do I include a text description on a downloaded ngx-qrcode

Tags: javascript, angular, qr-code

I've got a ngx-qrcode that I have implemented like:

[image: Html Code of ngx-qrcode]

I have a button that a user clicks and downloads the QR Code like :
[image: JS Code]

When downloading the QR Code I get a PNG that looks like this without any content.

[image]

How would I add a description to the downloaded PNG image so I can give the user a description of what the QR Code is eg:

[image]